# float value in - struct itimerspec

Tags: c, unix, timer, long-integer

I have this problem:
I have created a structure using the itimerspec structure. The itimerspec structure has two fields:

```
 struct timespec {
           time_t tv_sec;                /* Seconds */
           long   tv_nsec;               /* Nanoseconds */
       };

       struct itimerspec {
           struct timespec it_interval;  /* Timer interval */
           struct timespec it_value;     /* Initial expiration */
       };
```

So when i am entering:

```
enter code here
     struct itimerspec its; // argument to timer_gettime
      /* Setting timer interval */

       its.it_interval.tv_sec=0; 
       its.it_interval.tv_nsec=1;

      /* Setting timer expiration */
       its.it_value.tv_sec=0.1;  // First expiry after 1 sec
       its.it_value.tv_nsec=0;

     On compilation:
       prototype1.cc:115: warning: converting to ‘__time_t’ from ‘double’
```

My problem is: as per the design, the user can enter the timer expiration in whole numbers (1, 2, 3 etc which is fine) but can also enter time like 0.1 secs, o.2 secs etc. But only in seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to adjust to secs and nanosecs, e.g. 0.1 secs = 0secs and 100,000nsecs.

Comment: Ok, you mean 0.1 secs = 10^(8) nsecs. This is an acceptable solution. But is there no direct way, to fill this?

Comment: @kingsmasher1: timespec allows you to specify any time with a precision of nanoseconds. Just enter seconds and nanoseconds separately as tv_sec and tv_nsec.

Comment: Please see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457489/second-to-nanosecond-struct-itimerspec. I am now facing a new problem, using the above conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a double to a long val. If you need less than 1 sec you should express it in term of usec.

0.1 sec = 100000 usec

Do:

```
its.it_value.tv_sec=0;  // First expiry after 1 sec
its.it_value.tv_nsec= 0.1 * (usec in sec);
```

Comment: @Overbose: How? But the itimerspec doesn't take usec. itimerspec is needed by timer_settime.

Comment: @Overbose: Here is the prototype of itimerspec: long sys_timer_settime (timer_t timer_id, int flags, const struct itimerspec *new_setting, struct itimerspec *old_setting);

Comment: ITYM *assign* ? (Or at least I hope you do !).