# second to nanosecond - struct itimerspec

Tags: c, unix, timer, long-integer

i am populating the timespec structure. The intention is, user will always enter values in seconds (can also be 0.01 secs), so we are converting the seconds to nanoseconds using: `lt_leak_start = atoll(getenv("LT_LEAK_START")) * sec_to_nsec;` where variable `static long sec_to_nsec = 1000000000;` and then using it as an argument to settime: `timer_settime(timerid,0,&its,NULL)`. But on doing it an error occurs: `settimer failed: Invalid argument`

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

```
enter code here
 struct timespec {            
    time_t tv_sec;    /* Seconds */            
    long   tv_nsec;  /* Nanoseconds */      
  };         

 struct itimerspec {            
   struct timespec it_interval;  /* Timer interval */            
   struct timespec it_value;     /* Initial expiration */        
 };
```

The code i am trying is here:

```
static long sec_to_nsec = 1000000000;
lt_leak_start = atoll(getenv("LT_LEAK_START")) * sec_to_nsec;

/* Setting timer interval */

its.it_interval.tv_sec=0;
its.it_interval.tv_nsec=1;

/* Setting timer expiration */

its.it_value.tv_sec=0;  // First expiry after 1 sec
its.it_value.tv_nsec=lt_leak_start;

timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME,&sevp,&timerid);

if(timer_settime(timerid,0,&its,NULL)==-1) {
  perror("settimer failed");
  exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `timer_create` worked? You're not checking its return value.

Comment: Yes, it worked. I checked the return value. For simplicity, i did not put all those here. The error message is in `timer_settime` function, not `timer_create`.

Comment: Why're you taking a value in seconds and converting it to nanoseconds when you can just store it directly in `timespec.tv_sec` ?

Comment: @Erik: This is because `timespec.tv_sec` does not take fractional values.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: You don't have fractional values. You're working with an environment variable that you treat as whole seconds, and should store it directly in the tv_sec field.

Comment: @Erik: If i do that: `export LT_LEAK_START=2.2` i get a warning: `prototype1.cc:115: warning: converting to ‘__time_t’ from ‘double’ `

Comment: atoll produces a `long long` - your fraction is lost either way.

Comment: @Erik: Is it? Let me see it by a print statement. Anyways, kindly help me with the solution..please.

Comment: @Erik: Ohhh yes, it is getting lost. What conversion to use then to extract `int` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double d = strtod(getenv("LT_LEAK_START"), 0);
...
its.it_value.tv_sec=(time_t) d;
its.it_value.tv_nsec=(d - (time_t) d) * sec_to_nsec;
```

Read the environment variable as a double. Store the second part in tv_sec and the nanosecond part in tv_nsec.

Comment: Tons of thanks. But if we do like that. I mean populating both sec and nsec, do you think we can give values like `2.5 secs` as `its.it_value.tv_sec=2` and `its.it_value.tv_nsec=500000000`? I thought the user can either enter in seconds or in nanoseconds :(

Comment: @kingsmassher1: That's how you're supposed to fill in a timespec. A second part and a nanosecond part.

Answer (score 2):

`tv_nsec` must not be greater than 999,999,999. You are setting it greater than that.

Comment: So, what is the solution? If user is entering time as 0.1 secs, how to convert it to nanoseconds?. The design says and requirement says, user always enters time in seconds.

Comment: You perform a check. If it's bellow 1 sec, you do as you did, if its greater _or_ equal, you calculate the seconds separately and assign them to tv_sec while the rest goes to tv_nsec.

Comment: What to do if it is 2.5 secs? There are 2 components here. How to populate? Can we populate the tv_sec and tv_nsec separately in that case (will it work?). `tv_sec=2` `tv_nsec=500000000`?